# Data inside Firebase Database read twice with an observeSingleEvent

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

It's been now several hours I'm trying to dig Internet forums to try to find a solution to my problem and I can't figure out what's happening so I hope someone here can help)

I have a swift app and on one of my viewcontrollers, what I would want to do is to retrieve data from Firebase database and display them on my tableview.

Here you can see how my data are organized. [Firebase org of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5tHl.png)

To get the number of rows in my tableview, I put this into the viewWillAppear section

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Count the number contacts to get the correct number of lines in the table

        let ref_table = ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("emergencyContacts")
        print("Starting observing")
        ref_table.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot!) in
            print("Got snapshot")
            print(snapshot.childrenCount)
            let count = snapshot.childrenCount
            self.numberOfContact = Int(count)
            self.UI_contactsTableView.reloadData()
            ref_table.removeAllObservers()
        })
        print("Returning count")
    }
```

Then, to get the number of lines, I have this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Number of contact TV: \(numberOfContact)")
        return numberOfContact
    }
```

And to fill the cells of my tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contact-cell") as! EmergencyContactCell
        print("value of numberOfContact \(numberOfContact)")
        ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("emergencyContacts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
                print("snapshot value \(snapshot.value!)")

                for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    guard let restDict = rest.value as? [String:Any] else { continue }
                    let firstName = restDict["contact_firstName"] as? String ?? ""
                    cell.UI_fullName.text = "\(firstName)"
                }
            })
        return cell
    }
```

And I think this is where it gets bad because in the console, whatever I do, I constantly have 2 sets of data displayed so my cells are always filled with the same name as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uopc4.png).

This is also a capture of my console after program execution.

```
Starting observing
Returning count
Number of contact TV: 0
Number of contact TV: 0
Number of contact TV: 0
Got snapshot
2
Number of contact TV: 2
value of numberOfContact 2
value of numberOfContact 2
snapshot value {
    1ArkUu6pMPZPgf3pGFAvvxHiTPFaf5Cl =     {
        "contact_firstName" = Kate;
        "contact_lastName" = Bell;
        "contact_phoneNumber" = "(555) 564-8583";
    };
    s8haDrYYAT9Y12ZnmAfE87pDyjDZGwjx =     {
        "contact_firstName" = Daniel;
        "contact_lastName" = Higgins;
        "contact_phoneNumber" = "555-478-7672";
    };
}
snapshot value {
    1ArkUu6pMPZPgf3pGFAvvxHiTPFaf5Cl =     {
        "contact_firstName" = Kate;
        "contact_lastName" = Bell;
        "contact_phoneNumber" = "(555) 564-8583";
    };
    s8haDrYYAT9Y12ZnmAfE87pDyjDZGwjx =     {
        "contact_firstName" = Daniel;
        "contact_lastName" = Higgins;
        "contact_phoneNumber" = "555-478-7672";
    };
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help:)

Comment: Alright but why is it filling my cell badly then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I tried to have a total different reasoning and it worked. I actually used a handler to manage all this. I post my code here, it could help people in the same trouble as I was couple of hours ago.

```
var emergencyContactList = [EmergencyContact]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        fetchUsers()
    }

func fetchUsers() {
        refHandle = ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("emergencyContacts").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary  = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                print(dictionary)
                let emergencyContact = EmergencyContact()
                emergencyContact.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.emergencyContactList.append(emergencyContact)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.UI_contactsTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return emergencyContactList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contact-cell") as! EmergencyContactCell
        let _firstName = emergencyContactList[indexPath.row].contact_firstName ?? ""
        let _lastName = emergencyContactList[indexPath.row].contact_lastName ?? ""
        let _phoneNumber = emergencyContactList[indexPath.row].contact_phoneNumber ?? ""
        cell.UI_fullName.text = "\(_firstName) \(_lastName)"
        cell.UI_phoneNumber.text = "\(_phoneNumber)"
        return cell
    }
```

And I have a swift file apart EmergencyContact.swift

```
import Foundation

class EmergencyContact: NSObject {
    @objc var contact_firstName:String?
    @objc var contact_lastName:String?
    @objc var contact_phoneNumber:String?
}
```

Now it works like a charm!
Thanks TheAppMentor for having taken the time to answer me :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a an error in your cellForRowAtIndex Path method.

```
 `ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("emergencyContacts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in'
```

The above line returns all the emergency contacts each time the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is called.

In your for-loop you then always loop through and pick the last value.

You would need to extract the value for the particular index path.